# routes.rb is working locally but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Rephrasing my question to make it clearer.

Ok, I'm trying to build an app on heroku right now, but meanwhile, I want to redirect my users to an external url, example: `quickbrownfox.com`.

So what I'm trying to do is to modify the root route, so that whoever who tries to access my app will be redirected to the external site.

I attempted this by adding an entry to routes.rb:

`root :to => redirect('http://quickbrownfox.com')`

This works fine locally, but once I upload to heroku (bamboo stack). It seems that routes.rb is not being used. It is just trying to look for `index.html` which I had deleted.

Referring to the heroku logs, I'll get an:

`2012-02-10T03:42:10+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display a static page as your root, you should be using the High Voltage gem. This allows you to add static pages to your site as follows:

- Add `gem 'high_voltage'` to your `Gemfile`
- Put your static `home.html.erb` page in `/app/views/pages/`
- Route to your static page with `root to: => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :id => 'home'`

No redirects are necessary.

The High Voltage docs can be found at https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage.

Comment: this might be helpful. actually what im trying to do is to redirect anyone who comes in to another external url. im doing this so i dont have to tell them ive change url the next time my heroku app is ready .

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have not committed and pushed changes you made to routes.rb or index.html

Otherwise, I recommend you use Cedar stack in Heroku, save you a lot of time later in other issues since Cedar is more "natural"

Comment: i definitely pushed and committed the changes. i'm just not so sure why when the app is on heroku, it seems to go look for the index.html file without checking with routes.rb.

Comment: This won't fix the routing issue. The major perk of Cedar over Bamboo is that the asset pipeline, introduced in Rails 3.1, actually works.